# RPi3 with Mate: no HDMI output without Ethernet connection

Tags: hdmi, screen, ethernet-port

I'm running Mate (LTS) on my new RPi3. Everything is working fine as long as I plug in an Ethernet cable. If the cable is removed, my screen (connected via HDMI without adapters) immediately turns black. As soon as I again plug in the cable, it turns back on.

Any ideas?

// an empty Ethernet-cable does not give me the screen, only a cable with a connection helps (But a wifi connection has no influence)

Comment: Sounds pretty weird. Does the screen work if you unplug the ethernet cable *before* booting the Pi?

Comment: no. I wrote the image to the SD and was quite frustrated by the black screen (thought I made a mistake while writing the img) and only got an output when adding the Ethernet.

Comment: Anything in any way unusual about the other end of the ethernet cable? No [PoE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) or anything?

Comment: normal network with DHCP

Comment: If you feel like investigating this, I suggest plugging in a loopback cable (with pin 1 connected to pin 3 and pin 2 connected to pin 6). Otherwise, I would just try to return the board to the seller as defective.

Comment: Do you mean a ethernet cable with these pins connected? What should happen?

Comment: What is your power-source? Are you sure that is getting enough voltage-current? I have the same problem and it was that... If your charger is right then you probably have to adjust your /conf.txt file.

Comment: I bought a powerbank on amazon which should give me 1Amp at 5V. But I'll try with something stronger. How should I change the conf-file?

Comment: I described to problem to the vendor, they are going to send a replacement.